# How to make a responsive two row grid image view (2 x 2) in html bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a 2 x 2 responsive image grid view in made with bootstrap.

[DEMO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqVqK.png)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
     <div class ="col-md-2">
        <img src="download.png">
     </div>
     <div class ="col-md-2">
        <img src="download.png">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class ="col-md-2">
        <img src="download.png">
     </div>
     <div class ="col-md-2">
        <img src="download.png">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please give an example of your code or your error log to make it easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```css
.row{margin-bottom: 10px;}
.row img{margin:10px;max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" />
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```